# How do you get a list of VisualSVN users via TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn-server

We have a corporate VisualSVN Server hosting our code and I do not have access to the server. I am using TortoiseSVN as a client to manage my source code. Recently I had requested the admin to remove a bunch of devs' access to the repository.

How can I get a list of active users on the repo without having administrative access to the VisualSVN Server?

Comment: What you want requires certain permissions and it sounds like you don't have said permissions.  Get the admin to provide this information to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get list of users using Subversion client. The task is for administrator and should be performed on the server-side.

On the other hand, if you use VisualSVN Server 2.7 or newer, you can ask your administrator [to delegate you supervisory access](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00062/) to the particular repository. This way you could use [VisualSVN Repository Configurator](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/delegation/) tool to manage access permissions to repository. The Repository Management Delegation feature does NOT require you to be an administrator of the server machine.